# Google Sheets: VLOOKUP and Transcribing data based on multiple categories in the same column

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, pivot, vlookup, google-query-language

I'm trying to use vlookup between two tabs in a sheet where the data that exists in a single column denoted by "type" (tab B) needs to be transcribed into separate columns by type (tab A).

Edit:
For example, tab B has the "raw" data listed in just three columns: the type, the ID, and the value.

I would want tab A to be able to pull from tab B but organize it by the ID, then by the value associated with the type following it.

So, tab A would vlookup according to the ID, and then pull the associated value according to the column name (type): aaaaaa, bbbbbbb, ccccccc

Column Headers would be: ID, aaaaaa, bbbbbbb, ccccccc
and then the associated data will be filled out according to the ID and type match

I've only done vlookup where the filter is by what exists on tab A to trigger what to pull in tab B

```
=if((F236="aaa",VLOOKUP(A236, "TabName!$A$4:$AC"),24,FALSE), if(F236="bbb",VLOOKUP(A236,"TabName!"),24,FALSE))
```

I've attached a sample of how the two tabs have been set up for reference! Thank you!

[sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XbxL_m_p6ksIkKacsh9kJXsEjaHFpsRzMeKQGvJpsQs/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Define the identifiers for the values you need to retrieve: ie. what are "type"s? Also, what is your problem exactly?

Comment: Hi sorry! Added a bit of clarification to the top in terms of what I'm looking to pull. Essentially, tab a pulls value from tab b by ID and according to type. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=QUERY('sample database (tab b)'!A2:C, 
 "select B,max(C) 
  where B is not null 
  group by B 
  pivot A 
  label B'ID'")
```

[image]